# How to return NULL values when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

here are the contents of the tables.

```
mysql> desc student;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name       | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sex        | enum('F','M')    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc grade_event;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| date     | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category | enum('T','Q')    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| event_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc score;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| student_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| event_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| score      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display which students missed a quiz/test, found under 'category' in the grade_event table.

Here's what I've come up with, but am not generating any results;

```
select name, category, sc.event_id
from student s
join score sc on s.student_id=sc.student_id
join grade_event ge on sc.event_id=ge.event_id
where score is NULL
group by name, event_id;
```

I've also gone the route of attempting a subquery;

```
select name, category, sc.event_id
from student s
join score sc on s.student_id=sc.student_id
join grade_event ge on sc.event_id=ge.event_id
where score not in (select score from score)
group by name, event_id;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an outer join instead of an inner join to get list of students that do not have a corresponding record in the events after creating a carthesian join of students and events:

```
select name, category, ge.event_id
from (student s
join grade_event ge) --no join condition creates a carthesian join
left join score sc on s.student_id=sc.student_id and sc.event_id=ge.event_id
where sc.score is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just replace your `join` by `left join`, `join` is an `inner join` in MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

And take care with `group by event_id`, it can be useful to precise `group by sc.event_id`. I don't know in MySQL but in sql server it wouldn't work.

Your second query is necessarily empty as you ask a column to have its values not in its values :)

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but I'm still returning an empty set of results.

With the subquery, that makes total sense. What would be a better way to query?

Comment: Replacing the two joins by left join doesn't work ? Maybe it is différences between sql server and MySQL, it would work in sql as I understand how your tables are created. Anyway, @Shadow provided a working solution it seems